# Замена содержимого

Tags: javascript

Как на js заменить содержимое (например, всё что между `<body>`) на новое так, чтобы оно всегда было таким, на какое изменили? Если это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Например, воспользовавшись методом `.html()` (это в `jQuery`). Содержимое будет таким, пока страница не перезагрузится (если так можно выразиться). Написать "руками", тогда уж точно таким будет...